# Running different code in debug and release settings visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight

Is it possible in C# to do run specific lines codes in debug setting and other in say release settings.

```
if #debug

//run some lines of code

else 

// run different lines of code
```

Comment: What is it that you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 10):

You can do something like:

```
#if DEBUG
// Debug Code

#else
// Release Code

#endif
```

I use that in WCF services to run it as a console app in debug, but as a Windows Service in release

HTH,
Rupert.

Answer (score 3):

Read this blog post [If You’re Using “#if DEBUG”, You’re Doing it Wrong](https://blogs.msmvps.com/peterritchie/2011/11/24/if-you-re-using-if-debug-you-re-doing-it-wrong/), the author suggests using `System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute`:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
private static void DebugMethod()
{
    // Debugging code
}
```

Comment: I was looking for this exact thing. This is very exciting that it works so well!